# Eliminate Duplicate name

Tags: mysql, cakephp

```
public function search(){
            //$alphas = range('a','z');
            $alphas = $this->Breed->find('all', ['order' => 'Breed.name']);
            $this->set(compact('alphas'));
        }

<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <?php foreach($alphas as $alpha){?>
                  <li class="active">
                        <?php
                        pr(strtoupper($alpha['Breed']['name'][0]));
                            //echo ($this->Html->tag('a data-toggle="pill" href=#', strtoupper($alpha['Breed']['name'][0]), ['class' => 'letter']));
                        ?>
                  </li>
                <?php }exit; ?>
            </ul>
            <div id='#'>
                <?php echo $this->Html->para('breed', ''); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

o/p:
A
B
B
C

How I can get A B C?
What is solution to Eliminate Of Duplicate letter
What should I do to get this solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should add a little more details as to _why_ you're doing this in the first place. Currently your question reads a little [**xy-ish**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/227568), ie it's more about your attempted solution, rather than about the actual problem that you're trying to solve. Also please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the $alphas variable contains ordered names and you need to filter out only 1 name per alphabet i.e. only one name for A and so on.
In the foreach loop, you can do something like this:

```
$str = null;
foreach($alphas as $alpha) {

    if($alpha['Breed']['name'][0] == $str) continue; //skip all repetitions of a letter
    $str = $alpha['Breed']['name'][0];
}
```

PS: This is keeping in mind that the $alphas array contains a list sorted by name.

Comment: That will skip everything, as you're comparing one and the same value against itself.

Comment: Yup, my bad.. The lines got interchanged

Comment: Wrong it just showing the letter which is repetative. I want to eliminate it from list.